# How to loop on Devcomponents SuperGridControl and get values for checked items?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

On winform app
how to loop on Devcomponents SuperGridControl and get values for checked GridRow includeNested.
I tried this code, but only got root level. I need to loop through nested rows and get every checked value.

```vb
For Each item As GridRow In SuperGridControl1.PrimaryGrid.Rows
    If (item.Cells(0).GridRow.Checked = True) Then
        MsgBox(item.Cells(1).Value.ToString())
    End If
Next
```

[image]